# How to get tensorflow to do a convolution on a 2 x 2 matrix with a 1 x 2 kernel?

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I have the following matrix:

[image]

and the following kernel:

[image]

If I do a convolution with no padding and slide by 1 row, I should get the following answer:

[image]

Because:

[image]

[image]

Based the documentation of  `tf.nn.conv2d`, I thought this code expresses what I just described above:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_batch = tf.constant([
    [
        [[.0], [1.0]],
        [[2.], [3.]]
    ]
])

kernel = tf.constant([
    [
        [[1.0, 2.0]]
    ]
])

conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(input_batch, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
sess = tf.Session()

print(sess.run(conv2d))
```

But it produces this output:

```
[[[[ 0.  0.]
   [ 1.  2.]]

  [[ 2.  4.]
   [ 3.  6.]]]]
```

And I have no clue how that is computed. I've tried experimenting with different values for the strides padding parameter but still am not able to produce the result I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not correctly read my explanation in the tutorial you linked. After a straight-forward modification of `no-padding, strides=1` you suppose to get the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
k = tf.constant([
    [1, 2],
], dtype=tf.float32, name='k')
i = tf.constant([
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
], dtype=tf.float32, name='i')
kernel = tf.reshape(k, [1, 2, 1, 1], name='kernel')
image  = tf.reshape(i, [1, 2, 2, 1], name='image')

res = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv2d(image, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], "VALID"))
# VALID means no padding
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print sess.run(res)
```

Which gives you the result you expected: `[2., 8.]`. Here I got a vector instead of the column because of squeeze operator.

---

One problem I see with your code (there might be other) is that your kernel is of the shape `(1, 1, 1, 2)`, but it suppose to be `(1, 2, 1, 1)`.